# How to store/use Cookies in salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, cookies

I am trying to use 3rd party application within my lightning component. I have to store the access token received from the external app. I am planning to store that in Cookies.

But `ApexPages.currentPage().setCookies()` is throwing attempt to de-reference a null object error if I try to do this in my apex controller.

Also I cannot use `document.cookie` in my lightning helper because of Locker Service critical update.

Any help would be appreciated!